# JsonProperty names are not being respected on Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I would like to have custom names when writing my object but it's not printing what I have defined in annotation @JsonProperty:

```
data class Banking(
        @JsonProperty("personita_id")
        val clientId: String?,
        @JsonProperty("contita_id")
        val accountId: String?
)

val mapper = ObjectMapper()
val xpto = mapper.writeValueAsString(Banking("mammamia", "miaccuenta"))
```

xpto prints:

```
{"clientId": "mammamia", "accountId": "miaccuenta"}
```

What is missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can register the `KotlinModule` on the `ObjectMapper` from [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)

```kotlin
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
```

or depending on the used version

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule();
```